# ¿Como validar si una consulta tiene algún error en PHP?

Tags: php, mysql, pdo

Tengo una función de php donde realizo una inserción, pero quiero validar si la consulta tuvo un error o no, esta es mi función que tengo hasta ahora.

```
public function addtestfages($cuestions)
    {   
        $conexion = new Connection();
        $pdo = $conexion->getConexion();
        $statement = $pdo->prepare("INSERT INTO test (id_u_t, capture_date, question_1, question_2, question_3, question_4, question_5, question_6, consumption) VALUES (:id_u_t, :capture_date, :question_1, :question_2,  :question_3, :question_4, :question_5, :question_6, :consumption)");
        $statement->bindValue('question_1', $cuestions['question_1']);
        $statement->bindValue('question_2', $cuestions['question_2']);
        $statement->bindValue('question_3', $cuestions['question_3']);
        $statement->bindValue('question_4', $cuestions['question_4']);
        $statement->bindValue('question_5', $cuestions['question_5']);
        $statement->bindValue('question_6', $cuestions['question_6']);
        $statement->bindValue('consumption', $cuestions['consumption']);
        $statement->bindValue('id_u_t', $_SESSION['id_user']);
        $statement->bindValue('capture_date', date('Y-m-d H:i:s'));
        $statement->execute();
        if($statement)
        {
            echo 1;
        }
        else
        {
            echo "Hubo un error";
        }
        
    }
```

La tabla se llama test, pero si pongo test1 me sigue mandando el echo 1; como resultado, ¿alguna idea de como validar esta consulta?

Comment: Revisa el valor de `$statement->errorInfo()` después del `execute()`

Answer (score 0):

Cuando se hace INSERT, la BD devuelve el último id insertado, siempre y cuando haya definido un índice de tabla autoincremental (que es la mejor práctica). [Ver advertencia](https://www.php.net/manual/es/pdo.lastinsertid.php). En caso contrario, tendrás que verificarlo vía SQL haciendo otra consultas.

```
$statement = $pdo->prepare("INSERT ...");
// ... binding params 
$statement->execute();
$inserted_id = $pdo->lastInsertId();
```

Parecido en el caso del UPDATE o DELETE:

```
$affected_rows = $pdo->rowCount(); // <-- No usar esto con SELECT
```

Entonces si `$inserted_id` o `$affected_rows` `> 0`, se hizo una alteración en la tabla.

Answer (score 0):

`$statement->execute()` debería devolver true o false dependiendo de si la query se ha ejecutado correctamente o no.

Prueba con:

```
        $statement->bindValue('capture_date', date('Y-m-d H:i:s'));
        if($statement->execute())
        {
            echo 1;
        }
        else
        {
            echo "Hubo un error";
        }
```